# How to refresh Indicators?

Tags: indicator

If I add or remove an Indicator (my adding or removing a package) I currently have to logout or restart to see the effects of my changes.

How can I refresh my Indicators from within my session to enable me to keep working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try restarting the gnome-panel by hitting Alt+F2 and then typing `killall gnome-panel`.

Answer (score 9):

Just kill the relevant processes, this will work even if you don't uninstall first:

`killall indicator-sound-service`

For example, to get rid of the sound indicator after you've uninstalled it, or to refresh it.

Other services include:

- indicator-application-service (for the application menus)
- indicator-datetime-service
- indicator-me-service
- indicator-session-service (for the session menu at the far right)

Comment: This answer works in Unity and can be used to refresh the indicators even if they're not uninstalled.

Answer (score 1):

You could right click > remove it from the panel and add it back again; that's the easiest method, though not the best.

Answer (score 1):

You can do :

```
killall unity-panel-service
```

It does exactly what you asked.